# Are sequelize transactions atomic?

Tags: sequelize.js

I would like to use sequelize as an ORM for my REST backend. I just need to know something for sure, are sequelize transactions atomic, meaning there is no state inbetween a commited transaction and a rolled back one.
Heres an example:
A project always needs at least on person assigned to it at all times.
Workers and Projects have a many to many relationship, meaning it needs a Project-Association inbetween the two.
So in order for that condition to be true a project needs to be created and an association needs to be created in an atomic fashion. Sequelize allows for this, but it does not excplictly state that the transactions are atomic, only that they can be rolled back.
So in this example, is it possible, that the database is temporarily in a state where a project does not have anyone associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize transactions rely on configured RDBMS transactions so if your DBMS supports transactions as atomic (Do you know non-atomic transactions?) then you don't need to worry about Sequelize transactions atomicity.

Just don't forget to indicate a sequelize transaction in all CRUD Sequelize model methods.

There is an ability to read uncommitted transaction changes but that requires to set a special mode like READ_UNCOMMITED to read dirty records from a changed table. That's not the mode for everyday work and you should avoid it. Usually all RDBMSes uses something like READ_COMMITED mode by default for all connections to ensure a connection sees only committed changes.

Comment: what tipped me off is in https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html there is a manual rollback function. I thought this was really weird since the db would handle rollbacks automatically upon a commit and it implies theres a gap between commit and rollback

Comment: It's pretty normal because you can have two types of transactions in Sequelize: auto-commit transaction and a manual transaction. In the latter case you should manually call `commit` and `rollback` methods just like you do in SQL query: `START TRANSACTION; make some changes; COMMIT;`

Comment: Im pretty sure its impossible to rollback after a commit, whether or not it fails

Comment: I'm mostly about a ROLLBACK that you can call on your own conditions